# npm mongodb find query by ObjectID returns null

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Querying a poll by ID in the MongoDB shell perfectly works:

```
> db.polls.find({'_id': '5a89948a490ecd3123f47150'})
{ "_id" : "5a89948a490ecd3123f47150", "userName" : "Thomas", "pollName" : "\"What is your favourite mammal in the world?", "whale" : 0, "wholf": 0 }
```

For an unclear reason to me the query does not work in my Node.js application using npm mongodb. This is the query:

```
const getDb = require('./connection').getDb,
    ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectId;

...

   readPoll: async function (pollId) {
        let o_id = new ObjectId(pollId),
            cursor = getDb().collection('polls').find({
                _id: o_id
            });
        return await cursor.next()
    }
```

This is the result:

```
{"status": "success", "data", null}
```

Anybody familiar with this problem? Please find the project code [here](https://github.com/wassbeer/voting-app/tree/polls/services/polls). Thank you.

Comment: because your `_id` doesn't appear to be an objectId

Comment: Thank you Ayush. In that case, would you recommend simply providing the string value?

Comment: Yes I would, worth a shot, because in the shell query you're posting, you're passing in a srtring and not an objectId?

Comment: Correct. It worked! Thank you.